# Apache (with Nginx) redirects on directory listing

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, redirect, indexes, directory-listing

I have setup Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Apache. Everything seems to be working fine, although:

When i try to access an index-file (say index.php) but without specifying **the file itself**, and leaving out the **trailing slash** of the folder, Apache will redirect.

#### Example:

http://127.0.0.1/directory

I expect to see index.php - instead Apache will redirect to:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/directory 
... and show a "page not found" error.

#### Bonus info

Nginx listens on port 80
Apache listens on port 8080

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I stumbled upopn the answer:

> A "trailing slash" redirect is issued when the server receives a
>   request for a URL http://servername/foo/dirname where dirname is a
>   directory. Directories require a trailing slash, so mod_dir issues a
>   redirect to http://servername/foo/dirname/

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html